# How to check if an item is already in a model table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in my model Country, I have a column named :title. So in my new form, I want to validate to see if that specific title is already in the countries table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
end
```

This will cause the form to refuse the value if it's already in the table.